# Need help identifying facebook app which is referring visitors to our homepage

Tags: facebook, google-analytics

We're getting lots of visits today from what I think is an unidentified facebook app. Page urls include:

```
/?fb_source=canvasbookmark&count=0
/?fb_source=search&ref=ts
/?fb_source=canvasbookmark_more&count=0
/?fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=3_0
/?fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=6_0
/?fb_source=bookmark_seeall&ref=bookmarks
/?fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=16_0
/?fb_source=appcenter_request
/?fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=2_0
/?fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=8_0
/?fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=14_0
/?fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=17_0
/?fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=5_0
/?fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=7_0
/?fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=9_0
/?fb_source=bookmark_favorites&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=9_0
```

We didn't create this app. Is there any way to identify it?

Answer (score 1):

If it has the 'bookmarks' reference, it means the app is configured as a mobile or canvas app.

If it's a canvas app, these are likely POST requests to your server, not GET requests. 
The POST request will contain a `signed_request` parameter with some variables for your app

You can see information on what's in that `signed_request` using the Echo tool on Facebook's developer site: `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/echo?signed_request=SIGNED_REQUEST_HERE` - i'm not sure if it'll show you the app ID, but it may provide enough other relevant information to see what app people are trying to load